# AWS EC2 - How to create a backup locally/file system

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to backup EC2 instance locally? (Not just the data , but the installations on Linux in EC2 as well)

I found number of options that would take data backup, but is there a way where we could backup fully functional Ec2 as is to local system? If not, can we download the image may be of EC2 locally which can be restored to same/another AWS environment when needed?

Comment: You can export AMI. Review this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport_image.html. And this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html

Comment: Note, that any old school backup solution, like Bacula, will work on ec2 just fine.

Comment: I think the simple solution is to use AMI, using ebs snapshots, but ec2 backup locally it's possible for aws outposts: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/snapshots-outposts.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can we download the image may be of EC2 locally which can be restored to same/another AWS environment when needed?

for this the easiest solution would be this

- got to instances under ec2 service in your account management console.
- select the instance you wish to backup/copy.
- select create image.
- once image is created you can view it under ec2 navigation pane -> images-> ami.
- to launch instance from the image, select and launch it.

> could backup fully functional Ec2 as is to local system

the possible solution what i know and have tried to [use export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmexport.html#export-instance).*Exporting as a VM is useful when you want to deploy a copy of an Amazon EC2 instance in your on-site virtualization environment. You can export most EC2 instances to Citrix Xen, Microsoft Hyper-V, or VMware vSphere.*

your VM which is to be exported is stored in s3 so you will be charged according to s3 rates+ EBS snapshot charge

Comment: Can we delete copy of exported VM stored in S3? and reimport it when needed?

Comment: yes that can be done, if the answer helped you,would you mind to accept it as a solution to your question so that it may help others in the future. :)

Comment: use this command `aws ec2 export-image --image-id ami-id --disk-image-format VMDK --s3-export-location S3Bucket=my-export-bucket,S3Prefix=exports/` to export and refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html#import-vm-image to import

Comment: how long it takes for export instance to S3? I have 160 GB data on instance, and export task is in active state since 6+ hours now.